# How to get fontawesome "icons as bullet points" to get the property list-style-position: outside?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

So there is this link on the official font-awesome website about using their icons in a bulletpoint: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list

Which states you can do it like this:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

This looks like the icons are just being put in the li and not actually being the bullet points. Now I want to make sure whenever there's a new line of text for one of the bulletpoints, I want it to start on the same line as the text started on the previous line. However it's not doing that. It starts on the same line as the icon.

An example of how it is:

[image]

An example of how I want it:

[image]

(Ignore the table around it)

I have already tried `list-style-position: outside;`, but:

> list-style-position: outside; means that the bullet points will be
> outside the list item. The start of each line of a list item will be
> aligned vertically

So it sounds logical that the next line of text aligns with the icon cause the icons are part of the content of the list items.

Comment: I don't see any difference between how it is and how you want it, anyone sees it?

Comment: the difference in the images shown below "how it is" and below "how I want it" is not clear, could you please provide a clear picture of expected output to proceed with the solution

Comment: @RitikaGupta Sorry uploaded the wrong image

Comment: @Undry Sorry uploaded the wrong image. Should be fixed now.

Comment: The fontawesome's bullets are positioned as you wanted with the provided code. Could you show us the CSS your applying to `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Comment: @SeeoX No they are not? Try to make a bullet point 2 lines. You'll see the text goes straight under the bullet point.

Comment: On my phone so can't type a full example, but I used to do this by putting the FontAwesome icon in the `li::before` pseudoelement, and then positioning it manually to the left with CSS. You could probably do the same the way you have it  by absolutely positioning the icon to the left (and set position relative on the actual `li`)

Answer (score 1):

By default, it already behave as you want

Notes : can't show you code in comment. It isn't an answer to your question as you certainly have problem otherwise on your code.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="fa-ul">
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span>List with<br/>new line</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>List with<br/>new line<br/>new line<br/>new line<br/>new line</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span>hello, i have no new line</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. I dont want a border around it. I have "(ignore the table)" in my question. Look at the 2 screenshots and then at the bullet point thats 2 lines of both of them. That difference.

Comment: I know, but you see that it is wrapped as you want. You can remove the border, it was to show you that it behave as you want by default.

Comment: remove border and add more new line to show you without border the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The fontawesome's bullets are positioned as you wanted, outside.

This is done by the inclusion of the fa-li class in the span tag.

```
<span class="fa-li">
```

and the css that goes with it:

```
.fa-li {
    left: -2em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

This style is from fontawesome.css which needs to be included.